# How did my book see the rank and what is wrong with my null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

[image]

---

Reduced Row Echleon form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 3 & -2 \\ 2 & -1 & 4 & -5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta+6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta +6 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 & 3 \\ 0 & -5  & 6 & -11 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta+6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Surprisingly my book ends here and states :

> It is then a simple matter to deal with the cases θ ≠ −6 and θ = −6 .

**How come? I don't see how the rank becomes in the cases at this stage. How did the book see it! How is it simple to see this?**

---

Ofcourse, I paused the Row reduction

I had to continue by doing Column reduction:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\ 0 & -7 & 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta+6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta+6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Only now is it clear to me.

How did the book see the rank before these further steps? And by not doing column reduction.

---

For the Null Space, which matrix do I use? I am confused because look at this matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta+6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Using this I get :

$x=0, y= 0 , z= ? , (\theta+6)t=0$

But this is not obvious the Null Space. What is wrong with my Linear Algebra knowledge? Please help.

Comment: "How did the book see the rank before these further steps? And by not doing column reduction". What's your definition of rank?

Comment: *"Of course, I paused the Row reduction. I had to continue by doing Column reduction"* no you didn't.  And you shouldn't.  If you both row and column reduce, you can always end up with a matrix with $1$s on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kicker, here, is that the rank of a matrix is equal to the number of rows with non-zero entries in row echelon form. In the case that $\theta=-6,$ there are only $2$ such rows, while for $\theta\ne-6,$ there are $3$.

How are the rank and the dimension of the null space related?

As for the second part, remember that $\theta\ne-6,$ so $\theta+6\ne0,$ and so from $(\theta+6)t=0,$ we can conclude that $t=0.$ Consequently, a basis vector for $K$ will have the form $[x_1,y_1,z_1,0]^\dagger,$ as mentioned in the problem.

However, you should *not* be using column-reduction to find the null-space. Instead, you should continue on to find the RREF, keeping in mind that $\theta\ne-6.$ You should find equations with $x$ and $y$ dependent on $z,$ $z$ is a free variable (since it doesn't correspond to a pivot column), and the equation $t=0$.

Comment: Rank of a matrix is equal to the non zero entries? Really? But what I have been taught is that the rank is equal to the number of pivot columns. Dimensions = 4- rank

Comment: The number of rows with non-zero entries **is exactly** the number of pivot columns.

Comment: (+1) yes i understoood. Ummmmm, we can conclude that $t=0$ ? :D

Comment: But that is not a basis  :/ And what is $z=?$ it has no value.

Comment: Yes! However, you have gone a bit off track. I will expand my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for certain values of $\theta$, you can just divide the third row by $(\theta+6)$ to get a $1$ in that row.  When is this impossible?

Also, column reduction does **not** preserve null-space.

---

We now have the system of equations
$$
x + 2y + z + 3t = 0\\
-5y + 6z - 11 t = 0\\
(\theta + 6) t = 0
$$
In either case, we have
$$
y = \frac{1}5(6z - 11t)\\
x = -2y - z - 3t = -\frac{2}5(6z - 11t) - z - 3t
$$
From there, you just need to make sense of the last equation.

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much , it's impossible when $\theta=-6$

Comment: Usually the statement (+1) is followed by clicking the up-arrow.  Glad you found this helpful, at any rate.

Comment: I did +1 , donno where it disappeared. I Upvoted all three answers because all are helpful

Comment: About Null space, Cameron is telling Im almost close to finding the null space, but your telling the column reduction doesn't preserve it ?

Comment: Yes.  When $\theta \neq -6$, we deduce $t = 0$, so $x$ and $y$ should be solved for in terms of just $z$.  When $\theta = -6$, $t$ is a free variable, and it suffices to solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ and $t$.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I donno if you remember ;) but you have helped me before :)

Comment: Oh, 2 days ago. Hi again.

Comment: Yep ;) Thank you very much again :)

Answer (score 1):

For $\theta \neq -6$, you have three linearly independent rows. For $\theta = 6$, you have two linearly independent rows. Then you recall that the row rank and the column rank are the same things. Maybe this is how the author sees it. You can also think of it in terms of pivots ; for $\theta \neq -6$, you have three pivots, so the rank is $3$. For $\theta = -6$, you have two pivots, so the rank is $2$. Note that the rank plus the dimension of the null space equals $4$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

Hope that helps,